# Appium and Robotium - running tests remotely

Tags: android, robotium, appium

From what I have read Appium has a client\server architecture which allows you to run the tests from one machine (client) against devices plugged into a separate machine (server). Is this true?

Does Robotium support this?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out Robotium remote control:

https://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/RemoteControl

Comment: From the site "Robotium Remote Control makes it possible for Robotium test cases to be executed from the JVM. This enables Robotium to work with JVM frameworks like JUNit 4." Does this support the client server approach mentioned in my question? It is not obvious from the sites documentation.